# I am unable to update user profile like username, email and password from react application to my backend Nodejs and Express js

Tags: authentication, cookies, token

I try to build Movie Website and I designed my user controller and tried to implement on frontend. When I try to update user profile through Postman, it's working, but When I tried to update user details after registering and logging through the browser I am getting the message "Not Authorized, No Token". I implemented jsonwebtoken to create token and store it in cookies. The cookie is working well with postman but whenever I console the token value resulted from browser user update, it's **undefined**. How to solve this issue?

Comment: are the frontend and bakend working on the same domain?

Comment: @GeorgiStefkoff no it's working on different domain, backend on http://localhost:3000 and frontend on http://localhost:5173 and I am using rtk query to fetch the data.